# How to generate small apk in android

Tags: android, apk

I have prepared Android Applications which contains 8 Activities. 1st Default activity contains only two EditText to get username and password and 2 Buttons(one for login and other for new user registration) In registration activity there are 6 EditText and 6 TextView. and in remaining all activity there is only one TextView with Small line is written,

But when I check size of APK file it shows me 411 KB. How can I generate small APK.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why is this size bothering you? Are you putting it on a floppy disk? :P

Comment: I am seeking for a way to generate compact one, that's why

Comment: @AdarshPatel but why are you seeking to generate a smaller apk?

Comment: 411KB is very small already, why do you think it should be smaller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`411KB` is already pretty small for an android application.

Most are at least 1 or 2 megabytes. I don't think you need to worry about the size of your application as it stands at the moment.

However, if you really want to reduce the size of your APK, you could make sure to delete any redundant resources, or (as Richard Le Mesurier said) try using [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

To add to what Tom Leese said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22199433/383414), you could run ProGuard on your build.

That will result in an optimally small APK.

Edit your `project.properties` file and look for the line that says:

```
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

When you run an external signed build using the Android Tools menu, ProGuard will shrink your app.

More info on ProGuard here - http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#